# Random generated PHP IV is not working perfectly in IOS

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, cryptography, blowfish

The problem is the base 64 encoded iv(in PHP) doesn't match when decoded in IOS

The scenario is I am using Blowfish Algorithm CBC mode . Simply server(PHP) generate a random cryptographic IV
and encoded base64 format , send to IOS . 
The Problem is here when-time I try to decode , the decoded results are not correct always . Sometime it generates correct and rest of time error.

> Here is my PHP code.

```
public function ivGenerator()
{
    $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize, MCRYPT_RAND);
    echo base64_encode($iv);

}
```

Here is two result set of ivGenerator which i will use later for decoding

```
bTpkpLxMbNo=
aIvJeujxW7w=
```

> Here is my IOS code .

```
NSString *ecodedIVString = @"bTpkpLxMbNo=";    
NSData *ecodedIVData= [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:ecodedIVString options:0];
NSString *decodeIVString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:ecodedIVData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"decodeIVString  %@" , decodeIVString); // m:d¤¼LlÚ   //its correct
```

If I use ,

```
NSString *ecodedIVString = @"aIvJeujxW7w=";
```

Then the result is **hÉzèñ[¼**  , but the actual result should be  **h‹Ézèñ[¼**

I have tried

```
  NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding , NSISOLatin1StringEncoding ,      NSUTF8StringEncoding
```

But all of them are unable to generate accurate result (approx. 10  test I have found it).

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Don't use `MCRYPT_RAND` - there's nothing random about it and it's not cryptographically secure. Use `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` instead.

Comment: Have you tried `NSUTF32StringEncoding` ?

Comment: No its not working @Albert Renshaw

Comment: Do you have any idea, which character encoding use PHP to generate  MCRYPT_RAND ? @Narf

Comment: None. Or rather ... it has nothing to do with character encoding; it's raw binary.

Comment: Do not expect random bytes to be any printable string encoding and certainly not unicode, 8, 16, or 32 bit versions. Treat them as bytes, not characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should print out the result in hexadecimals and then perform a comparison.

It seems that the encoding on both platforms is the same (something you should not take for granted) so you get the same characters back. However, it isn't sure that the *font* or *font version* you are using shows the characters. It could also be that one platform shows an `‹` character for unknown encoding sequences, and the other doesn't show anything at all.

This brings us to the basic issue: if you decode random byte values then you may encounter byte sequences that do not translate to a character. So comparing binary strings by converting them to a printable string is no good. Instead you need to directly compare the bytes (e.g. by saving the IV to `iv.bin` files) or by translating them into hexadecimals.

It's extremely likely that the IV's are identical, despite the fact that the printout is different.